# insert data into jtable

Tags: java, swing

Hey I want to add data from the text fields into `jtable` on the click of a button.But when i'm doing this it is replacing the first row instead of adding another row.

Here's sample code Iam using

```
  DefaultTableModel  model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
  model.setRowCount(0);
  model.addRow(new Object[]{i, jTextField2.getText(), new Integer(jTextField3.getText()), new Double(jTextField4.getText()), new Double(jTextField5.getText())});
```

I want to add another row to table each time I click on `jbutton`

Comment: I guess your problem is in `model.setRowCount(0)`. `Sets the number of rows in the model. If the new size is greater than the current size, new rows are added to the end of the model If the new size is less than the current size, all rows at index rowCount and greater are discarded.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is in `model.setRowCount(0)`.

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setRowCount%28int%29)

> Sets the number of rows in the model. If the new size is greater than
>   the current size, new rows are added to the end of the model **If the
>   new size is less than the current size, all rows at index rowCount and
>   greater are discarded**.

More information [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)